# Slam Karto problem "No map received"

Tags: turtlebot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!!!

I'm using ros indigo and I've installed SLAM_KARTO from github. I'm using this package with the turtlebot simulator in gazebo and rviz but when I opened rviz, the Robot Model and the Laser Scan menu appears in red color and the Map and Costmap menu have the message `"No Map Received"`. So, I've changed the "Fixed Frame" from `map` to `base_footprint` and the Robot Model and the Laser Scan are solved but, the Map and Costmap are still with the message "No Map Received". I hope that you can help me.

Thanks in advance!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250784/slam-karto-problem-%22no-map-received%22/) by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-12-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miaow](https://answers.ros.org/users/36625/miaow/) on 2018-07-24**:
Hello!I have this problem too recently.Did you solve the problem?Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I did and fixed my problem was to comment out the remap line and change the "odom_frame" 's param value to "odom" in the karto_slam.launch file

---

Originally posted by [z3y50n](https://answers.ros.org/users/38705/z3y50n/) with karma: 16 on 2018-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0